# Infinite encirclement of branch cut

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, contour-integration

Consider the integral

$$I=\int _\Gamma\frac{1}{4+i(\log z)^2}dz$$

Where $\Gamma$ encircles the unit circle infinitely many times.

Would it then make sense to use a parameter n: encirclement count, $z=e^{i t}$ $\log z = i (t+2 \pi n)$

$$I[n]=\int^\pi _{-\pi}\frac{1}{4-i(t+2 \pi n)^2}i e^{it}dt$$

$$I=\sum ^ \infty _{n=-\infty}I[n]$$

Comment: Integrals do not depend on the parametrization chosen, that said, $I[a]=I[b]$ for every $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @Jorge second trip around will have a different argument, so it must have a different value.

Comment: the argument is still the same, you need to choose one branch of the logarithm before starting to compute the integral, otherwise it would not even be a function.